# How do I determine what went wrong with the failing tests on the build server?

Tags: .net, testing, automated-tests, tfsbuild

I'm running team build 2010, and I have a build definition with tests enabled. For some reason most of the tests are failing (that aren't failing on a developer machine), and I can't figure out why.

The build report tells me which tests failed and which tests passed, but it doesn't state why the failing tests failed. The visual studio tools tell me what's wrong, but I'm not running these tests in visual studio.

How do I determine what went wrong with the failing tests on the build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still open the test results from the build in Visual Studio -- that will give you more details about what is failing and why.

Comment: how do I "open the test results from the build in Visual Studio"?

Comment: I found it. It is on the build summary view of the build report. (I habitually go to the log because it has more information). There's a link "View Test Results".

Comment: @McKay -- glad you found it there.  I tend to use the Visual Studio interface just because it's the same one I use when I run the tests locally.  For reference if you ever wanted to try it, you can just open up the Build from Team Explorer in VS, scroll down to Result Details, click on the test run, and it will open up the Test Results panel in VS just as if you had run the tests locally.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing all of this from the VS interface.